# Environment variables / pip options in conda enviornment file

Tags: pip, conda

We can use `pip` in `conda` environment files as in below example via

```yaml
---
name: test-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python>=3.9
  - pip
  - pip:
    - mpi4py
    # alternative
    # - -r file:requirements.txt
```

For the pip installation step there are two important steps to do

1. set `export MPICC=$(which mpicc)`
2. run the install using `--no-cache-dir`

Is there a way to do that?

I can workaround 1 setting the variable before running `conda env create -f environment.yml` but it would be nice to have everything in a single file.

If it is not possible in the environment file, maybe something like this is possible in the a `requirements.txt` for `pip`?

Comment: yes it is possible in requirements.txt

Comment: Ok, would you mind giving an example?